# BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits equivalent in python

Tags: c#, python, double

I figure my best way of really getting a feeling about double precision numbers is to play around with them a bit, and one of the things I want to do is to look at their (almost) binary representation. For this, in C#, the function `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` is very useful, as it (after converting into hexadecimal) gives me a look at what the "real" nature of the floating point number is.

The problem is that I don't seem to be able to find the equivalent function in Python, is there a way to do the same things as `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` in a python function?

Thank you.

---

EDIT:

An answer bellow suggested `usinginascii.hexlify(struct.pack('d', 123.456)` to convert the double into a hexadecimal representation, but I am still getting strange results.

For example,

```
inascii.hexlify(struct.pack('d', 123.456))
```

does indeed return '`77be9f1a2fdd5e40'` but if I run the code that should be equivalent in C#, i.e.

```
BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(123.456).ToString("X")
```

I get a completely different number: `"405EDD2F1A9FBE77"`. Where have I made my mistake?

Comment: They are not completely different. They are the same bytes in reverse order. 405EDD2F1A9FBE77 is the more useful, because it shows the bytes, as pairs of hex digits, in the same order as in the IEEE 754 specification, so I would try to get the data into that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) and [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify)?

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('d', 0.0)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('d', 0.0))
'0000000000000000'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('d', 1.0))
'000000000000f03f'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('d', 123.456))
'77be9f1a2fdd5e40'
```

struct format specify `d` represent `double` c type (8 bytes = 64 bits). For other format, see [Format characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).

**UPDATE**

By specifying `@`, `=`, `<`, `>`, `!` as the first character of the format, you can indicate byte order. ([Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment))

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<d', 123.456)) # little-enddian
'77be9f1a2fdd5e40'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>d', 123.456)) # big-endian
'405edd2f1a9fbe77'
```